# Add fixed PID value to the process

Tags: debian, process

I need to set PID number of my process to fixed value, because I need to kill it with my application when some conditions are met, is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 5):

AFAIK. It is not possible to allocate particular PID to any program
but you can save your programs PID value by few ways

```
a. pidof PROGRAM_NAME => It will give you PID of that program
b. PROGRAM_NAME & PID_NO=$! => It will save PID of program into PID_NO variable
```